# Books about Turing machines and undecidability

Tags: reference-request, computer-science, self-learning, computability

I need help with finding literature about Turing machine and **undecidability**. First book I was suggested is *Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages, and Computation* by Hopcroft, Motwani and Ullman. I also found some notes (from different courses) about this topic online, but not books that have something specific about this. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Hopcroft is pretty much a standard book for Automata Theory and Formal Languages. It's pretty good.

Michael Sipser's *Theory of Computation* will be good for Automata Theory as well. It's a little easier than Hopcroft.

If you're dealing with Turing Machines, Undecidability, and NP generally, you  will find *Computers and Intractability* by Garey and Johnson useful as well.

Comment: Do any of these books has exercises possibly with answers?

Comment: Hopcroft and Sipser have exercises. Some solutions are available online. I think the same is true for Garey, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

A short wonderful (cheap) exposition can be found in the Dover book "Computability and Unsolvability" by Martin Davis. [http://www.amazon.com/Computability-Unsolvability-Prof-Martin-Davis/dp/0486614719](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486614719)

The previous book is a famous and classic one. Let me add one other tittle which I really like (it is a complementary one, it should not be used as a main book to understand these topics) and it is not so well-known: "Cornerstones of undecidability" by G. Rozenberg and A. Salomaa. [http://www.amazon.com/Cornerstones-Undecidability-Prentice-International-Computer/dp/0132974258](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132974258)

Comment: Thank you so much. Great books as I can see and very specific about my topic =)